# Using protobuf in servicestack, why order can only start from 1 not 0?

Tags: servicestack, protobuf-net

Using servicestack with protobuf, I found an interesting issue.

if I have the following class defined in both serverside and client side, it works

```
[DataContract]
public class Test : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string input { get; set; }
}
```

this doesn't.

```
[DataContract]
public class Test : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string input { get; set; }
}
```

Why order can only start from 1?

And reading this unit test, all orders of properties start with 1.
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/ProtoBufServiceTests.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Order=0` is the default value of an integer which is the same as not supplying a value.

Comment: may I suggest to add this piece of information on http://docs.servicestack.net/protobuf-format ?

Comment: @shawhu you're confused about a few things, the protobuf format uses the protobuf serializer which is an independent project and numerical indexes is how the format lays out fields, I.e it's essential to the format